# How to recover clash of clans account that was not on Google+

Tags: clash-of-clans

I didnt connect on google+ and then my phone was wiped so how do I recover my old base?

Answer (score 0):

You can not retrieve an account without signing in somehow, which is why the sign in is a thing.